# JS Code coverage YUI Issue with Extract Code Coverage Data

Tags: javascript, yui, code-coverage

I have been trying to get a code coverage tool for Javascript.
The steps should be to:

1. instrument the JS files
2. package and deploy on JBOSS
3. carry out testing
4. get the coverage dump
5. Generate report with coverage dump.

I tried to use JSCover but it did not work well while generating report.
Now I was looking at [Code-Coverage](https://github.com/yui/yuitest/wiki/Code-Coverage)
This tool looks good. I was able to Instrument the files with this, but I am stuck in the step where it says:

> Step 3 - Extract Code Coverage Data
>
> When all tests have been concluded, you can retrieve the code coverage
>   results in JSON format using:

```
YAHOO.tool.TestRunner.getCoverage(YAHOO.tool.TestFormat.JSON) (YUI 2)
Y.Test.Runner.getCoverage(Y.Coverage.Format.JSON) (YUI 3)
YUITest.TestRunner.getCoverage(YUITest.CoverageFormat.JSON) (standalone)
```

> This JSON structure represents all of the coverage data for the tests.
>   You can either manually take this data and save it to a file, or
>   submit this data to a server.

Not sure how carry out step 3.

Could anybody please explain this? We have been trying different tools for quite some time and are now stuck with this.

Comment: Have you tried [Istanbul](http://gotwarlost.github.io/istanbul/)?